# Old Mysql to new Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, phpmyadmin

I was learning some web design about 18+ months ago and got caught up on some other things and had to stop for a while. I'm getting back into web design again. I used xampp back then and using xampp now also. I found my old xampp zip of the entire folder. I extracted it thinking I might get lucky and get my databases back from mysql. I go into the xampp\mysql\data and I copied all the folders with the databases I wanted to put into the new mysql. I loaded up phpmyadmin and the databases are there but they are all empty.

The main database I want to save has these files inside of it...

db.opt
pcms_categories.frm
pcms_meta.frm
pcms_posts.frm
pcms_users.frm

so I see the table files there but mysql isn't loading them. I assume maybe it's an older version and it won't read these files because they are obsolete. I'm not sure. After transferring the files I stopped mysql and reloaded it so just wanted to mention that.

It's been so long ago that it doesn't exactly matter if I can recover this data. I was working on a blog though would be cool to get that back and finish what I started.

Comment: have you tried restarting your MySQl Service?

Comment: What was engine of tables?

Answer (score 0):

try to dump it to .sql perhaps?

in other word, export/import.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd check for permission issues. MySQL usually requires special permissions on its datafiles. Check to see if MySQL has created its own user/group. Next, I'd try to find out what version of MySQL you previously had, create an installation of said version, and use it to dump the datafiles to SQL.